# How to safe Consistency in DDD project in single aplication?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, mongodb

I want to design my project in DDD spirit. This is single aplication (not microservices) but with separate BC (as modules). Each BC have separate mongoDB collection.  I have problem with communication between bounded contexts inside single application. If two BC want to save some data into different collection. It may be some consistency problem. Do somebody know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

> If two BC want to save some data into different collection. It may be some consistency problem. Do somebody know how to resolve this problem?

The usual solution is to stop expecting that the two copies of the data will always be consistent.

Instead, we pay more attention to authority (who controls the "real" data?), and caching (how old is *this* copy?).

When two copies of the data *MUST* be synchronized, we design the system such that the two different use cases are in the same BC, and therefore share the same copy of the data.

There is no "magic" - data consistency is one of the things you give up when you start distributing the use of that data.

Comment: One single source of truth. Many records of what that single source of truth once was.